# Proper use of generics in list

Tags: java, list, generics

I have the following problem and I hope someone can tackle this. The setting is me having Lists of different entity classes from a psql call. I have the following method that I want to apply to them. I want to extract the names of the object and save them in an array for further use. Note: Every class I want to use has a `getName()` method.

```
private String[] getNamesOfList(List<EntityClassA> list) {
      namesArray = new String[list.size()];
      for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
          namesArray[j] = list.get(j).getName();
      }
      return Array;
}
```

Since I don't want to rewrite this method for every single class, I would like to use generics to generalize this. But I don't know how exactly. I have not worked with generics before and all the examples I have seen could not apply to this.

Comment: Do these classes have a common super class or interface?

Comment: They do implement the interface Serializable.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? If Java SE 8 then consider a Streams/ Lambda/ method reference approach to reduce the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the classes have a common super-class or interface, you can do:

```
private String[] getNamesOfList(List<? extends SuperInterface> list) {
      namesArray = new String[list.size()];
      for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
          namesArray[j] = list.get(j).getName();
      }
      return namesArray;
}
```

If they don't, you can introduce one and make all the classes which expose a `getName()` method implement this interface:

```
interface SuperInterface {
    String getName();
}
```

Comment: The generics here seems redundant, why don't just use List<SuperInterface> and that's it?

Comment: Because you won't be able to pass a `List<SomeEntityThatImplementsSuperInterface>` to the method.

Comment: @amit Better, `List<? extends SuperInterface>`

Answer (score 1):

With Java SE 8 (recommended if you use Oracle JRE unless you have support contracts with Oracle to get security updates for older Java versions) you can use:

```
private <T, R> List<R> map(List<T> list, Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper) {
    return list.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then:

```
List<EntityClassA> list = ...;
List<String> names = map(list, EntityClassA::getName);
```

With this code you can extract a list of *any* property from *any* list type.

As other mentioned, if you have a common interface such as

```
interface SuperInterface {
    String getName();
}
```

and only want to get names (no other properties) then you can use:

```
private List<String> getNames(List<? extends SuperInterface> list) {
    return list.stream().map(SuperInterface::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then:

```
List<EntityClassA> list = ...;
List<String> names = getNames(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if all your entities have the same field, it is better to refactor it out

You can have a super class that all other entity classes extend:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    private int id;
    private int name; 

    // creation date, modification date, if you need them

    //getters, setters
}
```

Then your entities would extend it. And then you can replace

```
private String[] getNamesOfList(List<EntityClassA> list) {
```

with

```
private String[] getNamesOfList(List<? extends BaseEntity> list) {
```